# CSRF mismatch when HTTP POST/PUT action is performed to sails.js backend using angular.js

Tags: sails.js, mean-stack

With every request I do pass csrf token from frontend. Still whenever I hit the api from frontend I do get the csrf mismatch error. On further debugging codebase, I found that the verifyToken routine from csurf is not validating it. Same works well when I try to hit the api from the postman.

Please suggest.